# Are there fees associated with activating the YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My client is looking to activate YouTube Data API and is wondering if there are any fees associated with enabling this. Can you please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube Data API v3 doesn't require to activate billing on your Google account and so no fees are associated with enabling this by default. According to [YouTube Data API Overview#quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)

> Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota allocation of 10,000 units per day
>
> Note: If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota by completing the Quota extension request form for YouTube API Services.